# Turning off a script from a script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject, unity-components

I need to turn off a script from another script in `Unity`. The script is in `C#` and the script I am turning off is in `JS`. Both scripts are attached to the same object. The error I am receiving says that there is no such thing as enabled. Any thoughts? Below is part of my code.

```
void Update ()
{   
    var walkScript = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").GetComponent ("CharacterMotor");
    if ((Input.GetKey ("p")) && (stoppedMovement == true)) {
        stoppedMovement = false;
        walkScript.enabled = true;
    } else if ((Input.GetKey ("p")) && (stoppedMovement == false)) {
        stoppedMovement = true;
        walkScript.enabled = false;
    }
```

The error I am recieving is as follows:

> Assets/Standard Assets/Character Controllers/Sources/Scripts/MouseLook.cs(41,36): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for`enabled' and no extension method `enabled' of type`UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class Component doesn't have a property enable. Try

```
Behaviour walkScript = (Behaviour)GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").GetComponent ("CharacterMotor");
```

Assuming it is a behaviour.

Comment: still getting an error: Assets/Standard Assets/Character Controllers/Sources/Scripts/MouseLook.cs(38,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Behavior' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: This is weird. Try using "UnityEngine.Behaviour" instead. But it is in the same namespace as GameObject and it seems to find that one? Maybe the error message is wrong and there is something else broken. If GameObject is available Behaviour should be available too. You include booth of them with "using UnityEngine;"

Comment: Now I get this: Assets/Standard Assets/Character Controllers/Sources/Scripts/MouseLook.cs(38,39): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Component' to `UnityEngine.Behaviour'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: How do I convert a component to a behaviour in Unity?

Comment: This is just basic object oriented programming.
`Component walkScript = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").GetComponent ("CharacterMotor");`  

//returns a component but a component can't be activated  
`//a Behaviour can be activated and Behaviour inherits from 
Component so you can cast Component to Behaviour using this:`  

`Behaviour bh = (Behaviour)walkScript;`

Comment: sweet. I just casted the component to a behaviour and it worked great.

Comment: Ok. My last comment was a bit of a fail. Most Components used in unity are actually MonoBehaviour (your own code) or Behaviour but the unity methods return it as Component so you have to cast it yourself! Good look with your project